# Fixing permissions on external drive

Tags: centos, permissions, non-root-user

I have created and mount my drive using root. And now I dont have permissions to write anything on it.

```
[ahmed@arkan Desktop]$ ls -al
total 12
drwxr-xr-x.  5 ahmed ahmed   74 Apr 21 17:38 .
drwx------. 21 ahmed ahmed 4096 Apr 21 11:15 ..
-rw-r--r--.  1 ahmed ahmed  558 Apr 14 22:56 mdadm config
drwxr-xr-x.  3 ahmed root  4096 Apr 16 21:24 Raid_Data
drwxrwxr-x.  2 ahmed ahmed   43 Apr 21 17:40 Sample HTML
drwxrwxr-x.  2 ahmed ahmed   47 Apr 21 17:28 Site
[ahmed@arkan Desktop]$
```

The drive name is Raid_Data. I tried fixing it but still, it is still under groups root.

Comment: Please add to the post the mount command; it would be far more easier to answer with that in your post.

Comment: I used disk application from gnome. So, I will post any command you ask me to.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
sudo -R chown ahmed:ahmed Raid_Data
```

This should work!